# Why does Java compiler can't differentiate the following two methods?

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, dex

I was working on an Android project and I accidentally wrote two methods, in almost same name. Here are they:

```
public static void GetUserBasicInfo(params...)
```

and another one is

```
public void getUserBasicInfo(params....)
```

In run time, Android/Gradle couldn't find the difference between them and gave a dex exception (we only had 350+ something methods).

Here is the catch: The code compiled and ran smoothly by a Ubuntu PC and windows PC. Only one OSX running laptop caught that as an exception! 
Is this a platform specific error because by definition, they are two different methods since Java is case - sensitive.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - you've only given pseudo-code at the moment, which makes it hard to tell whether the capitalization difference is real or not.

Comment: I have tried this but did not get any error. There must be something else you are missing. Please check once again.

Comment: @JonSkeet, this error occurred three days ago. And once the static method was deleted, the error resolved. Moreover, did not occur at my pc.

Comment: If you now can't reproduce the problem, we can't help you. If you can reproduce it again (not on your PC, but on the OSX machine) then you should do so, and provide a [mcve] as requested.